# Почему при выборке из двуз Баз данных при обращение в массиве показывает одно и тоже значение

Tags: php, mysql

Почему при выборке из двух баз данных при обращение в массиве показывает одно и тоже значение

```
$idhk = 'zhk.`zhk-id`';
$idobj = 'object.`zhk-id`';

$allroom = mysql_query("SELECT zhk.*, object.* 
            FROM zhk 
            LEFT JOIN object ON $idhk = $idobj ");
$arrall = mysql_fetch_array($allroom);

echo $arrall[0] ;
echo $arrall[1] ;
echo $arrall[2] ;
```

Выводит одно и тоже число

Задача объединить 2 базы данных по `zhk-id` (он у них одинаковый) `zhk` одно уникальное поле, а у `object` много полей с данным `zhk-id`

я всё верно делаю?

Comment: ON $idhk = $idobj. Вы указываете "таблица.колонка"? tablA.col1 = tabl2.col2

Comment: Попробуйте вывести var_dump($arrall) посмотрите что там за массив

Comment: Да указываю "таблица.колонка"

Comment: При var_dump($arrall); вывел массив, но только почему то там одна строка из двух таблиц, а их должно быть больше